# Find machine name and IP address in OOB SL5 app

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

How can I obtain the client machine name and IP address when running my Silverlight 5 application out-of-browser (i.e. installed on the local machine and NOT running via the web)?

Comment: Yes, thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there's no way to gather this information using just Silverlight.  You'd have to [do something like this](http://thewayithink.co.uk/post/2010/05/04/Mac-Address-in-Silverlight-4.aspx).  The short version is you use an AutomationFactory to create an unmanaged object which contains that information (in this case, a WMI Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration object).  That means this probably won't work on a Mac.  If you need something truly cross platform, it seems like the way is to create a really simple web service that simply returns the requestor's IP and hostname.

Comment: Wow, not as simple as I'd like but  that gives me something to look at.  Any idea if SL5 has addressed this in a managed way?

Comment: Not really. The best you could do would be p/invoke, but you were already running OOB with elevated trust so you already had that option.

Comment: Link is dead-ish; bounces to a blog main page instead of pointing at the specific article.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is your exact requirement .We had similar requirement some time back to get the local ip address to call a local service which is supposed to be present in client machine.

In that case we just built the local service url by hard coding the loopback address.ie localhost.

Comment: Not sure how that's supposed to help.  If I can't get the client's IP address or machine name, there's no way I can include it in a url.

Comment: Now I see your assertion that the service is running on the client machine. Obviously if that was the case, we wouldn't need the IP address of the client.  In this case we are calling services located on a different machine.

Comment: I believe your requirement is to obtain the client machine name...If you want to explore the network using com interop and call the service. But little difficult

Comment: Maybe my initial post isn't worded the best, so thank you for pushing the issue so I can clarify.  What I am looking to accomplish is to obtain the name of the machine (and/or IP Address) where the OOB SL4 app is running so that name/address can be passed as a parameter when calling web services located on a different machine.